# Angular HttpHeaders append new header from HTTP req

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I just started with Angular development and already hit first problem. I'm struggling with basics, i know...
I have a backend which I have to call with certain HttpHeader (project-id), which I get calling a http.get API.

I don't want to use httpInterceptor, since I don't want to add this header to all Requests.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  })
};

@Injectable()
export class OpenbatonService {

constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
  this.http.get(API_URL+'/api/v1/projects').subscribe((nsr)=> {httpOptions.headers.append('project-id',nsr[0].id)});
}

getAllNsrs(): Observable<any> {
  console.log("Executed before constructor is resolved")
  return this.http.get(API_URL+'/api/v1/ns-records', httpOptions);
}
```

So what I would like to achieve is to get projectId value from the API and use for all requests for OpenbatonService, but not for OtherService.

Comment: Refer https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19044

Comment: You misunderstood the way angular Http calls work. You need to create your specific header object, and then pass it down as a parameter to the `get()` function.

What you `subscribe()` to is your result from your backend.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you subscribe to a result from my backend. So I will try to create my own header object, but this object (the result of the API call) should already be resolved when I make next API call to my BackEnd with that projectId - how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `projectId` value to that service, and then just `append` the value to the `httpOptions` before making the actual `this.http.get()` call.
I made `projectId` optional in case other `getAllNsrs()` calls won't pass it.

```
const httpOptions: HttpHeaders = {  //<=== I'm just adding HttpHeaders type here
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          })
    };


getAllNsrs(projectId?: string): Observable<any> {  //<====Pass projectId
    if (projectId) {
        httpOptions = httpOptions.append('myProjectId', projectId);
    }

    return this.http.get(API_URL+'/api/v1/ns-records', httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: Look in this answer how the headers are being added to the `get()` function as a parameter. This is the correct way to do it.